# Selenium with Python: how to click preceding element

Tags: python, selenium, siblings

I'm working with a calendar and the only element I can access (due to non-askii issues) is a button that says 'Today' at the top of it.  Directly to the left is a left arrow that takes you back a month; similarly, directly to the right is a right arrow that takes you forward a month.  The html looks like this:

```
<tr style="-moz-user-select: none;">
<td class="button nav" style="-moz-user-select: none;" colspan="1">
    «
</td>
<td class="button nav" style="-moz-user-select: none;" colspan="1">
    ‹
</td>
<td class="button nav" style="-moz-user-select: none;" colspan="3">
    Today
</td>
<td class="button nav" style="-moz-user-select: none;" colspan="1">
    ›
</td>
<td class="button nav" style="-moz-user-select: none;" colspan="1">
    »
</td>
</tr>
```

I can click the 'Today' button by using:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='Today']").click()
```

Also, I can click the right arrow using 'following':

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='Today']/following::td").click()
```

However, I can not figure out how to click the left arrow (I believe with 'preceding').  This is what I'm trying and.. it says it is unable to find element with xpath == //...

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='Today']/preceding::td").click()
```

Is there another command I'm supposed to be using in order to find the previous element/sibling?

If it matters, I'm using IE9 and Selenium 2.44.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below xpaths:

**1-** For **clicking on the "<" arrow**:

```
//td[contains(text(),'Today')]/preceding-sibling::td[1]
```

Above xpath locates the **first preceding "td" element to the "td" element that has innerHTML/text as "Today"**.

**2-** For **clicking on the "<<" arrow**:

```
//td[contains(text(),'Today')]/preceding-sibling::td[2]
```

Above xpath locates the **second preceding "td" element to the "td" element that has innerHTML/text as "Today"**.

Answer (score 0):

While it does not use 'preceding', nor look at a sibling, I figured out how to do it like so:

```
precedes = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[text()='Today']/../td")
precedes[1].click()
```

It returns to the parent of the td containing 'today', and then finds the child td's and chooses the second one (index 1)